# Ubuntu 14 Nautilus Font is wrong

Tags: nautilus, fonts

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2188345/fonts.png]

As you can see, Nautilus font has suddenly stopped respecting the OS defaults. It happened by random after a boot today. Resetting fonts to default does not help.

Any ideas what's happening?

Edit: Link to full image https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2188345/fonts.png

Comment: Did you recently install MS Corefonts? (ttf-mscorefonts-installer package) My system is doing this tonight, and I installed the fonts earlier.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happened to me after installing the ttf-mscorefonts-installer package. I tinkered a bit and now Nautilus looks right again (it's back to using the Ubuntu font, as it normally does in Ubuntu).

Here is my procedure:

1) I opened a terminal and executed this fontconfig command:

```
$ fc-cache -rv
```

2) After the command finished, I logged out and logged back in.

I found other helpful font information in these questions:

[Firefox fonts changed after install ttf-mscorefonts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412828/firefox-fonts-changed-after-install-ttf-mscorefonts) (This is what convinced me there may be problems installing the ttf-mscorefonts-installer package.)

[Can I override fonts installed by ttf-mscorefonts-installer, prefer Liberation fonts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210590/can-i-override-fonts-installed-by-ttf-mscorefonts-installer-prefer-liberation-f?rq=1) (This is where I got the idea of trying a fontconfig command.)

UPDATE: As I mentioned in the comment below, I decided the ttf-mscorefonts-installer causes problems in recent versions of Ubuntu, so I removed it. Nowadays LibreOffice includes the Liberation fonts, which are metrically-compatible with three of the common fonts:

- Liberation Serif: same metrics as Times New Roman
- Liberation Sans: same metrics as Arial
- Liberation Mono: same metrics as Courier

If you don't use LibreOffice, you can get the fonts above by installing `fonts-liberation` package.

You can also match some other common Microsoft fonts:

- Carlito: same metrics as Calibri
- Caladea: same metrics as Cambria

The two fonts above are available by installing the `fonts-crosextra-carlito` and `fonts-crosextra-caladea` packages.

If you need a font compatible with Impact, Verdana, Trebuchet or Webdings, unfortunately I don't have a suggestion at this time.

Comment: After lots of back-and-forth upgrading and downgrading various things on a new system, I have decided the ttf-mscorefonts-installer causes all sorts of odd problems and most folks probably don't want to bother with it. I used to consider it almost essential for dealing with cross-platform font issues. For LibreOffice, the Liberation fonts are metrically-compatible with Times New Roman (Liberation Serif), Arial (Liberation Sans), and Courier (Liberation Mono), and the Carlito and Caladea fonts (both now provided with LO) are metrically-compatible with Calibri and Cambria respectively.

Comment: Update 6/2015: I found a [site](http://opensource-usability.blogspot.com/2015/05/fonts-for-desktop.html) which describes some more open-source font "equivalents," _however_ its focus is on fonts that **resemble** Windows fonts and they may not be metrically equivalent. (In other words, line-breaks and other text shapes will differ.)

Comment: Have you tried http://askubuntu.com/a/546404/16395 ? Fonts f****up happens sometime to me too, and deleting that file is normally the solution...

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem when replaced my HDD with SSD. Fonts started looking just like in your pictures! I solved this by disabling the Ubuntu user auto-login in a system. When I switch my laptop, I have to enter password to see desktop but fonts and themes are now looking correct.

Comment: It could be that disabling auto-login also somehow triggered a refresh of your font caches. Did you try the fontconfig (fc-cache -rv) command mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, I did. It didn't help.