# Nautilus fonts messed up each time after reboot

Tags: unity, nautilus, fonts

I'm seeing [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577999/ubuntu-14-nautilus-font-is-wrong) incorrect fonts every time the system boots.

When I run

```
fc-cache -rv
```

, log out, and log back in the correct fonts are restored, but I have to do this every time. How can I fix this permanently?

P.S. I'm on Ubuntu 15.10 x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem went away after the upgrade of compiz and compiz-config to version 0.9.12.2+15.10.20151015-0ubuntu1 just today. I guess it was a bug or an error in configuration files. But it could be a number of other things as well -- a lot of things were upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling auto-login while booting? This seemed to work for someone in the link you've given.

Comment: Auto-login is disabled in Ubuntu by default, it is also disabled for my account.